Understanding Feynman's Perpetual Motion Machine
I am currently reading Feynman's lectures on physics and I seem to have gotten stuck in a passage where he discusses Gravitational Potential Energy. Below is the passage causing me much confusion:
"Consider weight-lifting machines—machines which have the property that they lift one weight by lowering another. Let us also make a hypothesis: that there is no such thing as perpetual motion with these weight-lifting machines. (In fact, that there is no perpetual motion at all is a general statement of the law of conservation of energy.) We must be careful to define perpetual motion. First, let us do it for weight-lifting machines. If, when we have lifted and lowered a lot of weights and restored the machine to the original condition, we find that the net result is to have lifted a weight, then we have a perpetual motion machine because we can use that lifted weight to run some-thing else. That is, provided the machine which lifted the weight is brought back to its exact original condition, and furthermore that it is completely self-contained—that it has not received the energy to lift that weight from some external source—like Bruce’s blocks."
In short, I don't seem to get the definition of perpetual motion for a weight-lifting machine.
He says if the machine is restored to the ORIGINAL CONDITION and the net result is to have lifted a weight.. I don't get it. Firstly, what exactly is the original condition of the machine or what is meant by that anyway?
"If after a full cycle of operation, the machine has lifted a weight . . ."
My first pause here is: wouldn't it be lifting a weight anyway at any state? The only changes possible are which weight would be lifted at any given time - that on the left hand side of the seesaw-like machine or the right hand side?

Assuming I am wrong (about the state of the machine) and there is some state of operation in the machine where it wouldn't be lifting any weight, then it seems contradictory to say if when it has been restored to its original state (where it supposedly wasn't lifting weight) we find that it's net result is to have lifted a weight...

So which is it? An answer can't be simultaneously yes and no. It violates the principle of noncontradiction. If in the machine's original state/condition, it was at rest/equilibrium and wasn't lifting any weight how can we hypothesise a scenario where, having restored the machine to its original condition, we may find it to have lifted a weight? This is not my only confusion with the passage (I didn't want to quote large sections of the entire passage on gravitational potential energy) but I am starting from here. It all seems to be annoyingly unclear.

You should link to the online version of FLP. But you are just misunderstanding what he is saying. Look at Figure 4-2, and arbitrarily draw a vertical line separating the left side and the right side. Either side can be your machine; you get to choose. The other side is the environment that is temporarily considered separately, and then you can see that if you return the side you consider as the machine back to where it was, theoretically, you could have done somethng else to the environment, but the argument Feynman is giving you, tells you that this cannot happen.

Possible duplicate - Feynman Lectures: Why a non-reversible weight lifting machine cannot lift higher that a reversible one?
